# C++ DLL not exporting functions

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I'm developing a C++ library for export as a DLL in Visual Studio 2013 (C++ 11), and I'm running into a challenge where the library, once imported as an external dependency by another program, contains the classes that I wanted, but none of the functions of the classes are included.

[View of classes within external dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZulk.png)

I have included one particular class that is supposed to be part of this DLL export.

Here is my RegressionTrainer class header file:

```
#ifndef REGRESSION_TRAINER_H
#define REGRESSION_TRAINER_H
#include "MachineLearning.h"
#pragma once

#ifndef DLL_EXPORT
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

using namespace MachineLearning;

namespace MachineLearningTraining{

public class RegressionTrainer{
public:
    DLL_EXPORT RegressionTrainer();
    virtual DLL_EXPORT ~RegressionTrainer();

    std::vector<sample_type> DLL_EXPORT getInputData();
    std::vector<double> DLL_EXPORT getAugmentedOutputs();
    std::vector<double> DLL_EXPORT getNonAugmentedOutputs();
protected:
    pugi::xml_parse_result DLL_EXPORT setDataFile(pugi::xml_document &doc, char* file_name);
    void DLL_EXPORT setDataFolder(char* folder_name);
    std::vector<char*> DLL_EXPORT findDataFiles();
    char* data_folder;
    std::vector<char*> file_names;
    std::vector<sample_type> input_data;
    /*
    sample_type m;
    m(0, 0) = 14.86;
    m(1, 0) = 0.24;
    */
    std::vector<double> augmented_outputs;
    std::vector<double> non_augmented_outputs;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result;

    void DLL_EXPORT setInputData();
    void DLL_EXPORT setAugmentedOutputs();
    void DLL_EXPORT setNonAugmentedOutputs();
    virtual int DLL_EXPORT trainAugmentedModel();
    virtual int DLL_EXPORT trainNonAugmentedModel();
};
}
#endif
```

Here are the contents of MachineLearning.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <dlib/svm.h>
#include "pugixml.hpp"

namespace MachineLearning{
// Here we declare that our samples will be 2 dimensional column vectors.  
    typedef dlib::matrix<double, 3, 1> sample_type;

// Now we are making a typedef for the kind of kernel we want to use.  I picked the
// radial basis kernel because it only has one parameter and generally gives good
// results without much fiddling.
    typedef dlib::radial_basis_kernel<sample_type> kernel_type;
}
```

And here is my RegressionTrainer.cpp file:

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "RegressionTrainer.h"
#include "dirent.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace dlib;
using namespace MachineLearning;

namespace MachineLearningTraining{

RegressionTrainer::RegressionTrainer(){
    file_names = findDataFiles();
}

RegressionTrainer::~RegressionTrainer(){

}

pugi::xml_parse_result RegressionTrainer::setDataFile(pugi::xml_document &doc, char *file_name){
    return doc.load_file(file_name);
}

void RegressionTrainer::setDataFolder(char *folder_name){
    data_folder = folder_name;
}

std::vector<char*> RegressionTrainer::findDataFiles(){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    std::vector<char*> file_names;
    if ((dir = opendir(data_folder)) != NULL) {
        /* print all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            file_names.push_back(ent->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else {
        /* could not open directory */
        perror("Could not open directory");
    }
    return file_names;
}

std::vector<sample_type> RegressionTrainer::getInputData(){
    return input_data;
}

std::vector<double> RegressionTrainer::getAugmentedOutputs(){
    return augmented_outputs;
}

std::vector<double> RegressionTrainer::getNonAugmentedOutputs(){
    return non_augmented_outputs;
}

void RegressionTrainer::setInputData(){
    pugi::xml_document doc;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < file_names.size(); i++){
        setDataFile(doc, file_names[i]);
        std::cout << "Load result: " << result.description() << endl;

        pugi::xml_node measures = doc.child("case").child("measures");

        sample_type m;
        int count = 0;

        for (pugi::xml_node measure = measures.first_child(); measure; measure = measure.next_sibling()){
            m(count, 0) = measure.text().as_double();
            count++;
        }
        input_data.push_back(m);
    }

}

void RegressionTrainer::setAugmentedOutputs(){
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < file_names.size(); i++){
        setDataFile(doc, file_names[i]);
        std::cout << "Load result: " << result.description() << endl;

        pugi::xml_node output = doc.child("case").child("studyresults").child("averageangledeviation");
        augmented_outputs.push_back(output.text().as_double());
    }
}

void RegressionTrainer::setNonAugmentedOutputs(){
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < file_names.size(); i++){
        setDataFile(doc, file_names[i]);
        std::cout << "Load result: " << result.description() << endl;

        pugi::xml_node output = doc.child("case").child("studyresults").child("averageangledeviationAR");
            augmented_outputs.push_back(output.text().as_double());
        }
    }

    int RegressionTrainer::trainAugmentedModel(){
        return 0;
    }

    int RegressionTrainer::trainNonAugmentedModel(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Would welcome any thoughts!

Comment: You have to export classes, not their methods. If interface differs then you may use something else like interfaces or base classes and factories. Moreover do not export standard library objects unless you're ready to big headaches

Comment: Side note: you're importing into a managed assembly...is it your library an assembly?

Comment: Start up the wizard of the IDE and generate a DLL project to get an example. That said, you are supposed to extract a minimal example, so your question is off topic. Think about it: Who cares about your implementations of multiple functions if not even one function behaves as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing:

```
public class RegressionTrainer
```

Is this C++ or C#? Some other part of your code clearly shows it is C++. Therefore you must always put exact (or syntactically same) code.

Back to your problem, you cannot export members of a class. You must export entire class from a DLL.

Then issues start to begin. For one, you must expose (export or not, doesn't matter) all types the class uses (`pugi::xml_parse_result` for example). Then, you need to take care of different compilers versions (Even VC2015, various versions, debug/release, compiler settings etc). For example a `vector` on VC2015 debug build would be different from a release version. Service pack would complicate the problem.

In short: Don't export entire class having data-members. Even if entire data is private, you will need to export entire class, so that client (consumer of DLL) can compile and link (to code) properly.

So, what's the solution?

Well, just export a helper class:

```
class DLL_EXPORT RegressionTrainerHelper
{
    RegressionTrainer* pCoreClass;
};
```

Expose (export) all required methods (for the client) from this class. You'd just need to **forward the calls from helper to real** class.

Now, you might wonder, you will need to export the underlying **type RegressionTrainer**, and you are back to same problem.

Well, yes and no. If this helper class is being compiled within DLL, `RegressionTrainer` would be real thing. If not, just:

```
typedef int RegressionTrainer;
```

Pointer of anytype is of same size (32-bit or 64-bit). Hence the size of entire **exported** class would always match the size in DLL and in EXE.

**EDIT**
For example, there is a XML parser class, ParseXML, but it uses comlpex data members, you have a method `Parse`.

```
class ParseXML
{
// complex data members
// some private OR public datamembers and functions, you dont want/need to export
public:
void Parse(const char*); // or something different
};
```

You would want to export only `Parse`, through helper class.

```
class DLL_EXPORT Exported_ParseXML
{
private:
ParseXML* pCoreXMLInstance;
public:
Exported_ParseXML()
{
  // implementation in CPP
  pCoreXMLInstance = new ParseXML();
}
// The function!
void Parse(const char* pData)
{
  // FORWARD
  pCoreXMLInstance->Parse(pData);
}
```

The client will simply use the exported class:

```
Exported_ParseXML parser;
parser.Parse("XML-data");
```

The server compiler (DLL) would see `ParseXML` as real class type. But the client (EXE, or other DLL), would need see `ParseXML` as `int`. You got to figure out this!

Comment: Hey Ajay, appreciate the feedback and help! Just one quick point of clarification - what would 'forwarding the calls from helper to real' look like in terms of code? 

Also, if I do end up requiring it, where would I place that typedef?

Comment: I urge you to start coding. Without that you wont understand. For your clarification, let me further expand the answer.